# Need to wait for'KeyDown' Enter to accept TextBox text

Tags: c#

I need to have a way to set an integer in a method by taking the users input from a textbox. The problem is that I need to pause the code to allow input to be typed then to resume when 'Enter' is keyed. Keydown method works but not for setting a variable local to an outside method.
For instance:

```
....method()
{
    int num = 0;

    //wait for keydown Enter

    num = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text);
    //or 
    String s = TextBox1.Text;
    num = Int.TryParse(s);

    ....
 }
```

Comment: What happens when the user presses the Enter Key? Does another control receive the focus? If so, then simply use the textbox's Leave event.

Comment: It's just a way for it to not accept the text until it has been modified and submitted. Otherwise it just grabs the blank that it starts with. Also as well, the method is much more complex and if in a console app it would just be num=Int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine())

Comment: This is "console mode application" thinking.  Very inappropriate in a GUI, the non-modal way to allow the user to escape out of the Must Enter The Right Thing Now bounding-box.  If you don't have an OK button then use the Validating event.

Answer (score 0):

You should just generally change the control flow of your program. Either declare `num` at the class level, or call the method that depends on `num` from within the handler passing it `num`. Like;

```
  KeyDownHandler()
  {
      MessageBox.Show("Some Message");
      // or if you need something with more flexiblity
      OtherForm of = new OtherForm();
      OtherForm.Show();
      string someVal = OtherForm.TextBox.Text;
      MethodThatNeedsInputFromTextBox(int.Parse(TextBox.Text));
  }
```

MessageBox.Show method list;

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox.show(v=vs.71).aspx

You'll probably want to use something other than the default like the dialogue option which makes it so the messagebox retains focus until the user closes it.

Comment: Wouldn't that call the method after keydown, whereas I need to take input after a message is displayed and continue with the program

Comment: @user1884548 Okay I edited with some stuff on how to do it. You simply launch the form from within the event handler and use `ShowDialogue()` to force the user to respond to it before continuing execution.